# Does the Xperia X10 play Ogg Vorbis audio files?

Tags: music-player, media-player, audio, files, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

Or do I have to convert my OGG files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android supports ogg.

You create a folder on your sdcard called Music and Android will recognize it.

Here's a [list of supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).